# How to change array of strings to array of doubles?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am doing this as below:

```
val trainVector = trainingData.
  rdd.
  map { r => Vectors.dense(
               r.getDouble(4),
               r.getDouble(37),
               r.getAs(_).toDouble(70).toArray,
               r.getAs(_).toDouble(76).toArray))
```

I am getting the following error:

```
<console>:22: error: missing parameter type for expanded function ((x$1) => r.getAs(x$1).toDouble(70).toArray)
```

How can I change `r.getAs(_).toDouble(70).toArray` and `r.getAs(_).toDouble(76).toArray` arrays of strings into `array` of `double` (that I can use in `Vectors.dense` function)?

I tried the following but it does not work either as it array of string.

```
r.getAs[Array[Double]](70)
```

Comment: try `val trainVector = df.rdd.map(r=>Vectors.dense(r.getDouble(4).asInstanceOf[Array[Double]] ++ r.getDouble(37).asInstanceOf[Array[Double]] ++ r.getAs[Array[Double]](70) ++ r.getAs[Array[Double]](76)))
`

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume you have the following `trainingData`.

```
val trainingData = Seq(Array("1.1")).toDF("doubles")
scala> trainingData.printSchema
root
 |-- doubles: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
```

`trainingData` contains a single `doubles` column of type `Array[String]` that you'd like to map over to `Array[Double]`.

What I'd do would be to take that single `doubles` column (possibly with some other identifier column) and use Spark's `map` operator with Scala's `map` function inside.

```
val doubles = trainingData.
  select("doubles").
  as[Array[String]].
  map { strs => strs.map(_.toDouble) }
scala> doubles.printSchema
root
 |-- value: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: double (containsNull = false)
```

I think however that in the end it won't work since you have to transform the doubles to `VectorUDF` that is a `private[spark]`.